# Maintaining order when getting by entries by ID

Tags: templating, craft2

I'd like to get a certain set of entries in a specific order, but the element query comes back ordered by the default 'postDate desc'

```
{% set ids = ['4213','3200','4204','4212']
 %}

{% set orderedEntries = craft.entries().id(ids).order('id').all() %}

{{ dump(orderedEntries.ids) }} <- not the same order as the array!
```

It feels like there should be a relatively simple way of doing this in craft/twig, am I missing something? Or should I just resort to [SuperSort?](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by adding `.fixedOrder(true)` to your query:

`{% set ids = ['4213','3200','4204','4212'].fixedOrder(true) %}`

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/tag-queries.html#fixedorder

Comment: Thanks, how did i miss that?!

Comment: Came across this trying to pass a list of entry ids from an entry field into a Sprig component with pagination (Craft v4.4.x).
`{% set entryQuery = craft.entries().id(ids).fixedOrder(true).limit(limit) %}` 